# How does RabbitMQ WCF tolerate service failures?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rabbitmq

Suppose I have a WCF service that I bind/expose using the RabbitMQ WCF interface/binding. If I have clients that make calls to my service through the RabbitMQ WCF interface then what would happen if let's say the service goes down?

1. Would RabbitMQ just store the requests to that service and once the service comes up it will pass those requests to the service?
2. Would the client get a "service not found" message or some sort of "service is disconnected" message?
3. How is WCF connectivity implemented within RabbitMQ? Does RabbitMQ keep a queue where the WCF service requests go and if the service goes down then the queue just keeps growing until the service comes back online?

Comment: It would depend mostly on how you've configured RabbitMQ locally.  If the queue wasn't persistent, a crashed service would likely mean all the non-delivered messages would be lost.

Comment: @Peter, that sounds weird. If RabbitMQ was alive then no need to make the messages persistent - they should be stored until consumed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through some experimenting with the WCF API it doesn't appear like the client and the server are tightly coupled. I tried to bring up multiple instances of the client without the server coming up and there was no error. When I brought up the server it saw the message from the clients and responded to each client. So it looks like the client publishes a message onto the queue and when the server piece wakes up it takes the message from the queue.